# MySQL: Convert rows with multiple columns and insert into multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I created a table which listed 3 products with a column for each product. This worked very well for months - until of course I had to add more products.

**tblSubmission**

```
--------------------------------
|submissionID|Prod1|Prod2|Prod3|  
-------------|-----|-----|------
|101         |2    |0    |1    |  
|102         |0    |0    |1    |  
|103         |3    |6    |4    |  
--------------------------------
```

I've tried but can't get the table to split up into multiple rows grouped by submissionID, and adding the quantity of each productCode.

**tblSubmissionProduct**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|submissionProductID|submissionID|productCode|productQuantity| 
--------------------|------------|-----------|----------------
|1                  |101         |Prod1      |2              |  
|2                  |101         |Prod3      |1              |  
|3                  |102         |Prod3      |1              |  
|4                  |103         |Prod1      |3              |  
|5                  |103         |Prod2      |6              |  
|6                  |103         |Prod3      |4              |  
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

submissionProductID is defined as auto_increment

Is there an easier way to do this rather than using a split function?

Comment: You need it as a one-time conversion, right? If so, use `UNION ALL` of three separate queries..

Comment: Having a column for each product is a bad database design as you are finding out. You really need to add the products to their own table. This will save you a lot of work down the road.

Comment: yes. This is a one time execution. Going forwards , I'll have a Submission table (with core submission data) with the secondary table linked by the SubmissionID for the multiple products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with three `inserts` or `union all`:

```
insert into tbl_SubmissionProduct(submissionId, productCode, productQUantity)
    select submissionId, 'Prod1', prod1
    from tblSubmission
    union all
    select submissionId, 'Prod2', prod2
    from tblSubmission
    union all
    select submissionId, 'Prod3', prod3
    from tblSubmission;
```

Your new structure is a wise move.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, This works very well. 

I'll need to delete the empty rows (with 0 in the Quantity) and perhaps run a query to reorder the list by submissionID. But this had solved my biggest problem of splitting the table.

Thanks again